# GolangでDBのデータをそのまま返すAPIを作りたい

Tags: go, api, database

こんにちは。
タイトルの通りですが、DBのデータをそのままJSONにラップして返すだけのAPIを作りたいと考えています。
具体的な方法が思い浮かばず困っているのですが、参考になりそうな情報がありましたら教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「DBのデータ」とは、すべてのテーブルのデータですか？情報が足りず回答が不可能です。

Comment: 「リクエストを受け取る」「DBからデータを取り出す」「データをJSONに加工する」「JSONを結果として返す」等の手順に分解できると思いますが、その中でもどの部分が分からないのかをより具体的に書いてもらうとアドバイスも付きやすいと思います。

Comment: @htb コメントありがとうございます。DBのデータは全てのテーブルです。

Comment: @cubick ありがとうございます。DBからデータを取り出す部分において理解ができていません。

Comment: 質問は後からでも [編集] できますので、必要に応じて質問文を見直してみてください (そうすることでみんなの目に留まりやすくなります)。 / 例えばDBも「どの種類のDBなのか」といった情報があるとよさそうです。

Comment: http://gorm.io/ja_JP/ を使うと簡単にデータベースを操作できますよ。